# LiveData not updating when data changes

Tags: java, android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I'm using LiveData to fetch data from a server and observe it. My `onChanged()` method just gets called the first time, and does not get called when data in the server gets updated.

**UserFragment:**

```
UserViewModel userViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UserViewModel.class);
userViewModel.getUser().observe(this, new Observer<User>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(User user) {
        //Set UI
    }
});
```

**UserViewModel:**

```
public class UserViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private LiveData<User> user;

    public UserViewModel(Application application) {
        super(application);
        user = UserRepository.getInstance().fetchUser();
    }

    public LiveData<User> getUser() {
        return user;
    }    
}
```

**UserRepository:**

```
public class UserRepository {    
    private ApiService apiService;
    private static UserRepository userRepository;

    private UserRepository() {
        apiService = RestClient.getClient().create(ApiService.class);
    }

    public synchronized static UserRepository getInstance() {
        if (userRepository == null) userRepository = new UserRepository();
        return userRepository;
    }

    public LiveData<User> fetchUser() {
        final MutableLiveData<User> data = new MutableLiveData<>();
        Call<User> call = apiService.getUser();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<User> call, @NonNull Response<User> response) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    data.postValue(response.body());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<User> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                data.postValue(null);
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting a proper response from the server in Retrofit?

Comment: @Ümañgßürmån Yes

Comment: You'll need to **set value** to `LiveData` when you want to notify observers.

Comment: @JeelVankhede I already tried `data.setValue(response.body())`, but that didn't work

Comment: May be your API is executing prior to your observation of `LiveData`, try delaying your API call to check that.

Comment: @SaurabhThorat in which lifecycele method are you listening to your Observer.

Comment: @AmanRawat `onCreateView()`

Comment: @JeelVankhede You mean like this: https://github.com/hazems/mvvm-sample-app/blob/part1/app/src/main/java/com/example/test/mvvmsampleapp/service/repository/ProjectRepository.java#L65

Comment: @SaurabhThorat You should try the initialization and listening to your observer in onViewCreated() or onActivityCreated() .

Comment: @SaurabhThorat yes, try that for an instance, if i'm right on this meaning i can help you solving issue and will post solution to this. just let me know.

Comment: @JeelVankhede Delay didn't work. I also tried debugging and it doesn't go into `fetchUser()` in `UserRepository` after server data change.

Comment: @SaurabhThorat Have you tried the solution i mentioned?

Comment: @AmanRawat That didn't work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is that fetchUser creates a new `LiveData<>` every time you call it.

This means that your first one will never receive an update.

Please take a look at these...

## Repository

```
public class UserRepository {    
    private ApiService apiService;
    private static UserRepository userRepository;

    private UserRepository() {
        apiService = RestClient.getClient().create(ApiService.class);
    }

    public synchronized static UserRepository getInstance() {
        if (userRepository == null) userRepository = new UserRepository();
        return userRepository;
    }

    // Your example code
    public LiveData<User> fetchUser() {
        // Your problem lies here. Every time you fetch user data, you create a new LiveData.
        // Instead, fetch user should update the data on a pre-existing LiveData.
        final MutableLiveData<User> data = new MutableLiveData<>();
        Call<User> call = apiService.getUser();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<User> call, @NonNull Response<User> response) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    data.postValue(response.body());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<User> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                data.postValue(null);
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        return data;
    }

    // My alterations below:
    private MutableLiveData<User> userLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public LiveData<User> getUser() {
        return userLiveData;
    }

    public LiveData<User> fetchUser2() {
        Call<User> call = apiService.getUser();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<User> call, @NonNull Response<User> response) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    userLiveData.postValue(response.body());
                }
                // TODO: Consider a fallback response to the LiveData here, in the case that bad data is returned. Perhaps null?
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<User> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                userLiveData.postValue(null);
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        return userLiveData;
    }
}
```

## ViewModel

I would also change this slightly. Instead of observing fetch, I would observe the LiveData directly.

```
user = UserRepository.getInstance().getUser();
```

Later, you can request updated data from the server at any point.

```
UserRepository.getInstance().fetchUser2();
```

You could also call `fetchUser2()` on the first construction of `UserRepository`. Then only updates would call `fetchUser2()` directly.

```
private UserRepository() {
    apiService = RestClient.getClient().create(ApiService.class);
    fetchUser2();
}
```

## Fragment

Also, in your Fragment, do not observe on `this`. Instead use `getViewLifecycleOwner()`

```
userViewModel.getUser().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<User>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(User user) {
        //Set UI
    }
});
```

Comment: would you mind to explain what's the difference of using `this` vs `getViewLifecycleOwner()` ?

Comment: It changes what the `LiveData` binds to. The problem is that `Fragment` lives much longer than you might expect. This can lead to observing the same `LiveData` multiple times. `getViewLifecycleOwner()` will actually bind to the lifecycle of the fragments `View`. So when the view hierarchy is destroyed, the `LiveData` observers will be unbound too.

Comment: For a more official explanation, there is also this link from the docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#getViewLifecycleOwner%28%29

Comment: It still doesn't update. And with this code, even after the fragment is destroyed and finished, it still shows the old data.

Comment: You might consider adding logs to the code in all places. Log in your repository under `fetchUser2()` to ensure that the LiveData is being transmitted to, for example. So log in `fetchUser2()` directly, in `onResponse()` and in `onFailure()`. Double check that you aren't still using `fetchUser()` in your code, if you just copy and pasted.

Comment: Additionally, about showing old data, that is part of the point of having a `ViewModel`. It retains state through rebuilding. If that is a problem for you, you will need to invalidate that yourself when starting the Fragment.

Comment: is `fetchUser2()` really required? Can't it be done with just one method? And regarding old data still being shown, afaik ViewModel clears data after observers lifecycle has ended. Here it still showed old data.

Comment: I also debugged it, the code simply doesn't go in any repository method.

Comment: Well, you can delete the old `fetchUser()` method, and rename `fetchUser2()`. You can also just observe `fetchUser()` and not `getUser()` if you want to. I personally prefer to separate concerns where possible. Where are you trying to refresh the data? Do you have a button in your `Fragment`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184016/discussion-between-saurabh-thorat-and-knossos).

Comment: `onChanged` is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution!, I was facing the same issue.