# Live Data Observer called only once. It is not updating the data from server when api is called again to update UI

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-livedata, observer-pattern

I looked for many articles and tried to understand how Live Data is observe changes when MVVM architecture is used.

I have a Fragment A, ViewModel and Repository class.
ViewModel is initiated in `onCreateView()` method of the fragment.
Api call is initiated just after that in `onCreateView()` method of fragment.
Data from the Server is **observed** in `onViewCreated` method of the fragment.

For the first, it is running perfectly fine. But When I update the user name from another Fragment B and come back to Fragment A.

Api is called again in `onResume()` method of Fragment A to update UI. **But here my Live Data is not observed again and UI is not updated**

I didn't understand what I am doing wrong? Why observer is not triggering second time?

Below is the code

```java
class FragmentA : Fragment(){

    private lateinit var dealerHomeViewModel: DealerHomeViewModel
  
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_dealers, container, false)

        val dealerHomeFactory = DealerHomeFactory(token!!)
        dealerHomeViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this,dealerHomeFactory).get(DealerHomeViewModel::class.java)

      dealerHomeViewModel.getDealerHomeData()
        return view
    }

 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
          dealerHomeViewModel.dealerInfoLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, androidx.lifecycle.Observer {dealerInfo ->
            // Update UI
            tvDealerName.text = dealerInfo.name
        
        })
    }

 override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        dealerHomeViewModel.getDealerHomeData()
    }
}

//=========================== VIEW MODEL ===================================//
class DealerHomeViewModel(val token:String) : ViewModel() {

    var dealerInfoLiveData:LiveData<DealerInfo>

    init {
        dealerInfoLiveData = MutableLiveData()
    }

    fun getDealerHomeData(){
        dealerInfoLiveData = DealerHomeRepo().getDealerHomePageInfo(token)
    }
}

//======================== REPOSITORY ================================//
class DealerHomeRepo {

    fun getDealerHomePageInfo(token:String):LiveData<DealerInfo>{
        val responseLiveData:MutableLiveData<DealerInfo> = MutableLiveData()
        val apiCall: ApiCall? = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofit()?.create(ApiCall::class.java)
        val dealerInfo: Call<DealerInfo>? = apiCall?.getDealerInfo(Constants.BEARER+" "+token,Constants.XML_HTTP)

        dealerInfo?.enqueue(object : Callback<DealerInfo>{
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<DealerInfo>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d(Constants.TAG,t.toString())
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<DealerInfo>, response: Response<DealerInfo>) {
                if(response.isSuccessful){
                    when(response.body()?.status){
                        Constants.SUCCESS -> {
                            responseLiveData.value = response.body()
                        }

                        Constants.FAIL -> {

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })

        return responseLiveData
    }
}
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken you should use .postValue(result) on your LiveData instead of .value = result

Comment: @GregoryNowik How .postValue(result)  is differ from .value = result

Comment: I just know you have to use postValue() instead of assassinating the value because it's a mistake I made.

See : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53407529/8609783

Comment: I doubt that's relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are generating a NEW mutableLiveData each time you use your `getDealerHomePageInfo(token:String` method.

First time you call `getDealerHomePageInfo(token:String)` you generate a `MutableLiveData` and after on `onViewCreated` you observe it, it has a value.

In `onResume`, you call again `getDealerHomePageInfo(token:String)` that generates a NEW MutableLiveData so your observer is pointing to the OLD one.

What would solve your problem is to pass the reference of your `viewModel` to your repository so it updates the `MutableLiveData` with each new value, not generate a new one each time.

Edited Answer:

I would do something like this for `ViewModel`:

```
class DealerHomeViewModel(val token:String) : ViewModel() {
    private val _dealerInfoLiveData:MutableLiveData<DealerInfo> = MutableLiveData()
    val dealerInfoLiveData:LiveData = _dealerInfoLiveData


    fun getDealerHomeData(){
        DealerHomeRepo().getDealerHomePageInfo(token, _dealerInfoLiveData)
    }
}
```

And this for the `DealerHomeRemo`

```
class DealerHomeRepo{

    fun getDealerHomePageInfo(token:String, liveData: MutableLiveData<DealerInfo>){
        val apiCall: ApiCall? = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofit()?.create(ApiCall::class.java)
        val dealerInfo: Call<DealerInfo>? = apiCall?.getDealerInfo(Constants.BEARER+" "+token,Constants.XML_HTTP)

        dealerInfo?.enqueue(object : Callback<DealerInfo>{
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<DealerInfo>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d(Constants.TAG,t.toString())
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<DealerInfo>, response: Response<DealerInfo>) {
                if(response.isSuccessful){
                    when(response.body()?.status){
                        Constants.SUCCESS -> {
                            liveData.value = response.body()
                        }

                        Constants.FAIL -> {

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

For Observers, use the LiveData as before:

```
dealerHomeViewModel.dealerInfoLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, androidx.lifecycle.Observer {dealerInfo ->
            // Update UI
            tvDealerName.text = dealerInfo.name
        
        })
```

Comment: can you please elaborate how it can be done passing view model to repo class.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. I got this we are sending new reference of MutableLiveData from View Model to Repo and from Repo class will update values and Live Data is observed.

Comment: @Dnveeraj nice!, if my answer solved your problem, you could select it as the accepted answer!